# Adding two large binary numbers

Tags: java, binary

I am trying to add two larger binary numbers (i.e. number of bits are greater than 31) but stuck due to getting `NumberFormatException`. Below is the line which is throwing exception-

```
Integer.parseInt(binaryNo, 2);
```

My idea was to convert both binary numbers into `integer` first, then adding together after that convert `integer` to binary back using `Integer.toBinaryString(integerSum)`. But it's not applicable for binary number having bits larger than 31 as integer overflow occurs. Please tell me any way which can perform large binary number addition in optimized way (minimum time). Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). Construct it with:

```
public BigInteger(String val,
                  int radix)
```

Your radix in this case is 2. Note that each `BigInteger` is immutable so you perform arithmetic slightly differently:

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger(...);
Biginteger j = new BigInteger(...);

BigInteger sum = i.add(j); // neither i nor j are modified
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just use [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead. It has arbitrary precision, can handle arbitrary base numbers (in your case with binaries, base 2) and should be fairly well optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class:

```
BigInteger first=new BigInteger(binaryNo1, 2);
BigInteger second=new BigInteger(binaryNo2, 2);

BigInteger result=first.add(second);
String binResult=result.toString(2);
```